# If $A \in \mathrm{GL}_n(R)$, $A^l=1$, what do we know about $\mathrm{char}(A)$, the characteristic polynomial of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

> Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $R$ be a (connected, if needed) $K$-algebra. Let $A \in \mathrm{GL}_n(R)$ such that $A^l=1$ for some $l$. Is it true that $\mathrm{char}(A)= \mathrm{det}(XI_n-A)= \prod_{i=1}^{n}(X- \lambda_i)$, for some $\lambda_i$ with $\lambda_i^l=1$?

This is certainly true if $A$ is triangularisable. This is e.g. always true if $R=K$. Also if $R$ was an integral domain, we could embedd it into the algebraic closure of its fraction field. But what about general $R$? I quickly tested the case $n=2$, $l=2$, and the statement seems to hold true there. But computations get very ugly. Maybe somebody knows a counterexample or a nice trick to see this?

Comment: The word you're looking for is triangularisable (triangularizable to the Americans).

Comment: At the very least, $A$ satisfies
$$
\prod_{i=1}^l (A - \lambda_i) = 0
$$
if we take $\lambda_i$ to be the $l$th roots of $1$.  However, I don't know if we have any sort of Cayley-Hamilton theorem in this context.

Comment: If by Cayley-Hamilton you mean $\mathrm{char}(A)(A)=0$, then this holds over arbitrary commutative rings (see e.g. Theorem 4.3 in Eisenbud, Commutative Algebra with a view...). But how did you get $\prod_{i=1}^n(A-\lambda_i) = 0$ (for some $\lambda_i$)? Thanks for commenting and for the help with my bad vocabulary.

Comment: Note that if you take *all* the roots of $1$, you should end up with
$$
\prod_{i=1}^l (A - \lambda_i) = A^l - 1
$$

Comment: When you say $K$-algebra, exactly what are you assuming?  Unital, I guess; associative?  commutative?

Comment: Commutative, associative, unital.